NextJs with react can we load rendered component and re-rendered with new data
Nextjs with react, Is it possible to create a dummy client component in server rendering? Once client data is available, it will load that component with key or placeholder render with new data Is it possible?
my code:
ServerComponent.jsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import templateMap from "../utils/templateMap";
import PlaceholderComponent from "../utils/PlaceholderComponent";



const renderComponent = ({data }) => {
   // console.log("renderComponent"+JSON.stringify(data))
  if ( !data) {
    console.error("Template or data is undefined:", {  data });
    return null;
  }

  const Component = templateMap[data.templateName];
  if (!Component) {
    console.error(`Template ${template} not found.`);
    return null;
  }

  // Recursively render nested children
  const renderedChildren =
    data.childs && data.childs.length
      ? data.childs.map((child) => {
        

          if (child.renderType === "CSR") {
            // ServerComponent.js
console.log(`Rendering placeholder with ID: ${child.id}`); 
<PlaceholderComponent key={child.id} id={`placeholder-${child.id}`} /> 


            return renderComponent({ data: child });
          }
//console.log(`placeholder-${child.id}`+"Render a placeholder for CSR data"+child.id)
          // Render SSR or other types recursively
          return renderComponent({ data: child });
        })
      : "Loading client-side data...";
 console.log(data.id+"data.id renderedChildren"+renderedChildren)
  return (
    <Component key={data.id} data={data}>
      {(renderedChildren )}
    </Component>
  );
};

export default function ServerComponent({ ssrChilds }) {
  const [serverData] = useState(ssrChilds);

  return (
    <div>
      {serverData
        ? serverData.map((child) =>
            renderComponent({ data: child })
          )
        : "No data available"}
    </div>
  );
}

ClientComponent.jsx
use client
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client"; 
import DynamicComponent from "../utils/DynamicComponent";
import { fetchCSRData } from "../utils/FetchDataTypeHandlers";

export default function ClientComponent({ csrChilds }) {
  const [clientData, setClientData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchClientData = async () => {
      try {
        const fetchedData = await fetchCSRData(csrChilds);
        setClientData(fetchedData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching client-side data:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchClientData();
  }, [csrChilds]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (clientData.length > 0) {
      clientData.forEach((child) => {
        const placeholder = document.getElementById(`placeholder-${child.id}`);
        if (placeholder) {
          console.log(`Replacing placeholder with ID: ${child.id}`); // Log for debugging
          const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(placeholder); 
          root.render(<DynamicComponent key={child.id} data={child} />);
        } else {
          console.warn(`Placeholder with ID ${child.id} not found.`);
        }
      });
    }
  }, [clientData]);

  return null;
}

I tried with this code but
document.getElementById(`placeholder-${id}`); 

always coming null, what is the issue for this? Can someone give the solution? It will be helpful for me
Nextjs with react is it possible to create dummy clientcomponent in server rendering? Once client data is available, it will load that component with key or placeholder render with new data Is it possible? I want to render client data with in the placeholder. Is this the correct way to do it?
